# Convexity of an alternative Rate-Distortion function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, information-theory, coding-theory

An alternative way of writing the rate-distortion function is:
$$D(R) =\min_{p(\hat{x}|x):\ I(x;\hat{x})\leq R} \mathbb{E}[d(x,\hat{x})],$$
where $x,\hat{x}$ are variables, $d(x,\hat{x})$ is a distortion (e.g., hamming, or squared difference).

I want to prove that this is convex in $R$, which is what I saw on a source without a proof.

I can see that the function is decreasing since an increased $R$ will increase the feasible space, so decrease the minimum value. But I can't prove the convexity.

Comment: Found it (page 257): https://fuentes.inta.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/565/2017/01/solutions2.pdf

Comment: Note that $p(x)$ is treated as given here. The objective is linear in the decision variables (the $p(\hat{x}|x)$). The constraints are that $\sum_{\hat{x}} p(\hat{x}|x) = 1$ for every $x$, which are again linear, and that $I(X;\hat{X}) < R.$ It is a standard result that for fixed $p(x)$, mutual information is a concave function of the the test channel $p(\hat{x}|x)$. Try to show this. Using this the convexity of the set $\{p(\hat{x}|x): I(X;\hat{X}) < R\}$ is straightforward. Since the intersection of convex sets is convex, this tells you that the constraint specifies a convex set.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 how can you conclude the objective Is linear in the distribution?

Comment: $$ \sum_{x, \hat x} p(\hat{x}|x) p(x) d(\hat{x}, x) = \sum_{x,\hat{x}} a_{x,\hat{x}} p(\hat{x}|x)$$ is a linear combination of the decision variables. Oh, also, there are non-negativity constraints, but they're also obviously convex.

Comment: thank you @stochasticboy321